# Async Express middleware, how does it know

Tags: node.js, express

So I have my Express (4.0) configuration:

```
app.get('/api/tracks', (req, res) => {

});
```

In it I want to query elasticsearch:

```
app.get('/api/tracks', (req, res) => {
    client.search({
        index: 'someindex',
        type: 'sometype',
        body: {
            query: {
                match_all: {}
            }
        }
    }, (err, resp) => {
        res.json(resp);
    });
});
```

This is clearly an "async" request because of the callback situation.

**How does Express know to hang around till you send something, because by all accounts, the `response` could have been sent out when search had finished executing.... (way before the ES request had finished)**

If Express makes use of like some kind of event use, so calling something like `res.end()` to signal the end of the response, why doesn't it do that on all normal `get`'s or `post`'s and leave them open?

Because:

```
app.get('/api/profile', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ user: 'callum' });
});
```

Works normally and the `response` according to the browser has finished....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `res.json()` only once. Consider this example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/json1', function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.json({ok:true});
  }, 2000);
});

app.get('/json2', function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.json({ok:true});
    res.json({ok:true});
  }, 2000);
});

app.listen(3333);
```

When you access it with:

```
$ curl http://localhost:3333/json1
```

You get this after 2 seconds:

```
{"ok":true}
```

But if you try to access it with:

```
curl http://localhost:3333/json2
```

Then you still get this on your client side:

```
{"ok":true}
```

But your server crashes with:

```
_http_outgoing.js:344
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
```

It means that Express waits for the `res.json()` and finishes the request as soon as it gets one, but after that point you cannot call it second time.

The same happens with `res.send()` - e.g. see those routes:

```
app.get('/send1', function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.send('ok');
  }, 2000);
});

app.get('/send2', function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.send('ok');
    res.send('ok');
  }, 2000);
});
```

On the other hand, it seems that you can call `res.end()` twice and the second call gets ignored:

```
app.get('/end1', function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.end('ok');
  }, 2000);
});

app.get('/end2', function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.end('ok');
    res.end('ok');
  }, 2000);
});
```

But if you use `res.write()` instead of `res.end()` then the request will wait for the `res.end()` and never finish:

```
app.get('/end1', function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.end('ok');
  }, 2000);
});

app.get('/end2', function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.end('ok');
    res.end('ok');
  }, 2000);
});
```

But the message actually gets delivered - which you can observe by ending the message by "\n" to make `curl` show it when it arrives:

```
app.get('/write1', function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.write('ok\n');
  }, 2000);
});

app.get('/write2', function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.write('ok\n');
    res.write('ok\n');
  }, 2000);
});
```

So as you can see, there are certain ways to send data - like `res.write()` that can be used many times and doesn't close the connection. There are other ways like `res.json()` that can be used only once and they implicitly close the connection.

But if you add a route like this one:

```
app.get('/empty', function (req, res) {
});
```

Then Express will wait forever with the connection open because it has no way to tell whether `res.end()` or `res.json()` will be called in the future. It can only know whether it has been called already or not yet.

Comment: So basically, the connection is kept open until you `send` or `json` something on the `response` or it times out.

Comment: @CallumLinington Yes. But for the timeout (on the Express side) you have to use a middleware like `connect-timeout` with `var timeout = require('connect-timeout'); app.use(timeout('5s'));` or something like that. Otherwise Express will wait probably for the timeout on the client side, or a timeout of a TCP connection.